# Unreproducible crash: [__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I keep getting crash reports with the following crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

What could be triggering this crash? An empty array or something that is not an array at all? I am not able to reproduce the crash myself, I just can see it in crash logs.

Comment: `__NSArrayI` is a(n immutable) subclass of the `NSArray` class cluster. Hence, your object **was** an array. This is really strange, however, since `NSArray` is known to implement that method…

Comment: Post the complete stacktrace and relevant code.

Comment: The relevant code is inside a framework, and I don't see the stack trace because the crash is reported to me by HockeyApp and all I see is the exact call of `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`.

Comment: @Banana Upload your dSym files to hockeyapp and you will see the crash trace. That's debugging basics.

Comment: You should add exception break point and run the code again; `1. In the bottom-left corner of the breakpoints navigator, click the Add button.
2. Choose Add Exception Breakpoint.`

Comment: Also, if you are using hockeyapp, you should at least know system version or whether the devices are jailbroken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have a memory issue, the fact that you can't regularly reproduce it also suggests a memory issue.

The error you are getting is saying, "we tried to call this method on this object you have a pointer to, unfortunately the object is not the type of object you told me it was going to be."

I can really only speculate given the information you've provided. Take a really fine tooth comb through your code and make sure you are not changing that object prior to that crash happening.

Try adding a debug check to make sure its the correct class. NSAsserts are **NOT** the solution, they are not even compiled into production apps but, it should help find the cause of the error.

```
NSAssert([myObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]], @"aw snap its not an array!");
```

Post more info and I can try to help further

Comment: Messaging a `nil` object is not an error in Objective-C. For an object of class `__NSArrayI`, the assertion will succeed, since `__NSArrayI` inherits from `NSArray`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am not able to give you much more information, since the array I send the message to is a return value of a framework method and I am not able to see how the framework creates this value, i.e. is it really an array, is it nil, etc? I want to understand what could provoke such a crash and then to check for it before sending the `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` message.

Comment: So to conclude, if the object were nil, this would not be a crash, therefore the object is something else other than NSArray, but not nil?

Comment: Yes correct, objective-c allows you to send messages to nil objects with no crash. My guess is somehow that object is being modified and no longer accepts that selector call.

Comment: No. I am almost sure this is not correct answer. Memory corruption of system classes? They are stored very far from allocated application memory. This could be caused by some bad method swizzling, for example. However, we can't know without a stack trace. This is only wild guessing.

Comment: What does method swizzling mean?

Comment: @Banana Method swizzling means replacing method implementation in classes by another implementation. Some frameworks do it (e.g. `AFNetworking` does it). If they do it wrong, bad thing happen.

Comment: @Sulthan it's not the corruption of the class, it's the corruption of an object. any object can be corrupted in memory if you have a pointer to it, regardless of whether it's a "system" class (what does that even mean?).

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant An object can get corrupted of course, however, the probability of memory corruption to overwrite a part of `NSArray` class memory space (not the instance, the instance has only the `isa` pointer, it doesn't store methods) to trigger  a completely different exception, is pretty low.

Comment: @Sulthan I know that instances don't store the methods.